# Prove that for any real numbers $a, b, a^4+b^4+2 \geqslant 4ab$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I was given a hint to use AM-GM here, but I am no sure how to create an arithmetic or geometric mean here because of the exponents.

Comment: Hint: write LHS as $a^4+b^4+1+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the hint should be an answer, I [post it as community wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1149/290189).

Use AM-GM on $a^4$, $b^4$, $1$ and $1$.

\begin{align}
\frac{a^4+b^4+1+1}{4} & \ge\sqrt[4]{a^4\cdot b^4 \cdot 1 \cdot 1} \\
a^2+b^2+2 &\ge 4|ab| \ge 4ab
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

I've got another way of solving it, one without AM-GM:

\begin{align}
a^4+b^4+2 & \ge 4ab \\
a^4-2a^2+1+b^4-2b^2+1+2a^2+2b^2 & \ge 4ab \\
(a^2-1)^2+(b^2-1)^2+2a^2-4ab+2b^2 & \ge 0 \\
(a^2-1)^2+(b^2-1)^2+2(a-b)^2 & \ge 0 \\
\end{align}

The sum of squares is always greater than $0$, because the square of any number is greater than or equal to $0$. Hence the inequality $a^4+b^4+2 \ge 4ab$ holds true.

Answer (score 0):

Two times  AM-GM:
$$
(a^4+b^4)+2 \geq 2a^2b^2+2=2(a^2b^2+1) \geq 4 ab
$$